# Changing the color of a jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a couple of spans with the class of 'find'. In my jQuery i have 2 variables, correct and nope. Correct = 'Yes' and nope='No'. When either of these 2 variables are in the classes.text() they pop up yes and no. But what i can't figure out is how to change the colors of the variables. I want 'correct' to have the color green when 'yes' is in the spans and i want nope to have the color of red. Not really good at explaining this but hope you get what i'm trying to say.

Code:

```
<span class="find"></span>
<span class="find"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var correct='Yes';
        var nope='No';
             if($('.find').text() == correct) {
                   $(this).css({color: 'green'});
             }
         $('.find').text(correct);
</script>
```

Comment: What does Java have to do with this question?

Comment: @DavidConrad Maybe he tagged java, because of **JAVA**script ? ;)

Comment: Variables don't have colors. You're trying to change the color of an HTML element based on its content.

Comment: @DamianKozlak They eternally trolled newbies by naming it "java-script" I mean seriously, couldn't ecma-script just do?

Comment: Just a side-note... This kind of thing is often done with input fields, since they have a value. If you do use inputs, you don't even need Javascript. I updated [my demo at CodePen](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/OMprRK) to show an example.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful, you should  upvote them and choose a 'selected' answer. This helps maintain stackoverflow as an involved community.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you utilize CSS classes for the coloring. In this way, you are not applying CSS directly using jQuery, making your code more modular and allowing for easier changes in the future.

For example -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $find = $('.find')
  $find.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() === "Yes") {
      $this.addClass('correct');
    } else if ($this.text() === "Nope") {
      $this.addClass('incorrect');
    }
  })

})
```

```css
.correct {
  color: green;
}
.incorrect {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="find">Yes</span>
<span class="find">Nope</span>
```

Comment: ^This. There's only two possible states, so making a classes to define each state and jQuery to change what class applies is the way to go. Allows you to make any design changes in the CSS instead of JS, and allows you to make a lot more complex and visually appealing differences between the two states instead of just sticking with color because that's what's easy to swap in JS

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is your selector is seeing multiple values in `.find`, because you're selecting both of them.  What you need to do is something like this:

```
var correct='Yes';
var nope='No';
$('.find').text(correct);
$('.find').each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == correct) {
    $(this).css({color: 'green'});
  }  
})
```

Also notice that you have to set `$('.find').text(correct)` BEFORE checking for your comparison--otherwise it's just an empty string.  Here's a fiddle you can play with:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj9p2ucp/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` doesn't have any value the way you're using it.

Here's an example that works:

```js
var Correct = 'Yes';
var nope = 'no';
$('.find').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == Correct) {
    $(this).css({
      'color': 'green'
    });
  } else if ($(this).text() == nope) {
    $(this).css({
      'color': 'red'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="find">Yes</span>
<span class="find">no</span>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/OMprRK